# "cannot open file 'user32.lib'" when trying to use Visual Studio 2005 on Windows 10

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2005

I'm attempting to match output with a C++ Win32 executable compiled with Visual Studio 2005, so I'm trying to use that MSVC to do so. I have a project defined in CMake. I open "Visual Studio 2005 Command Prompt", but when I try to `cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" ..` I get `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'user32.lib'`.

Here's the `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

# set the project name
project(LEGOStarWarsSaga)

# add the executable
add_executable(LEGOStarWarsSaga src/main.cpp)
```

Here's the Visual Studio 2005 Command Prompt output:

```
C:\Users\aprim\Documents\lstsc>mkdir build

C:\Users\aprim\Documents\lstsc>cd build

C:\Users\aprim\Documents\lstsc\build>cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" ..
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 14.0.50727
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 14.0.50727
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/bin/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/bin/cl.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:66 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/bin/cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Users/aprim/Documents/lstsc/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):nmake /nologo cmTC_41947\fast &&       "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"  -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_41947.dir\build.make /nologo -L                  CMakeFiles\cmTC_41947.dir\build
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_41947.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
        C:\PROGRA~2\MI30EB~1\VC\bin\cl.exe @C:\Users\aprim\AppData\Local\Temp\nmBDB4.tmp
    testCCompiler.c
    Linking C executable cmTC_41947.exe
        "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_41947.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\MI30EB~1\VC\bin\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\MI30EB~1\VC\bin\mt.exe --manifests -- C:\PROGRA~2\MI30EB~1\VC\bin\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\cmTC_41947.dir\objects1.rsp @C:\Users\aprim\AppData\Local\Temp\nmBE13.tmp
    LINK Pass 1: command "C:\PROGRA~2\MI30EB~1\VC\bin\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\cmTC_41947.dir\objects1.rsp /out:cmTC_41947.exe /implib:cmTC_41947.lib /pdb:C:\Users\aprim\Documents\lstsc\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_41947.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:X86 /debug /INCREMENTAL:YES /subsystem:console kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:CMakeFiles\cmTC_41947.dir/intermediate.manifest CMakeFiles\cmTC_41947.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1104) with the following output:
    LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'user32.lib'
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"' : return code '0xffffffff'
    Stop.
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
    Stop.





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/aprim/Documents/lstsc/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/aprim/Documents/lstsc/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

After reading online, I've come to find that this is something to do with missing the Windows SDK. However, I have the Windows SDKs 7.1 and 10.0 installed. What am I missing?

Bonus points if there's a build tool that'll make this process (nearly) seamless for anyone cloning the project.

---

EDIT: Installing Visual Studio 2005 Professional with the full Visual C++ option installs the SDK properly, and the project builds. My worry is that not everyone has access to VS 2005 Pro.

Comment: Okay I have questions. 1.) Why are you using Nmake? It's really really slow. I don't recommend it. 2.) How are you linking user32.lib? 3.) What version of cmake are you using? 4.) Can you post the cmake that causes this linker error?

Comment: @hdf89shfdfs 1) I'm using NMake because the CMake docs said "NMake Makefiles" is the replacement for Visual Studio 2005 from 3.12 onwards, and I need to use the VS 2005 toolchain. 2) I'm not, for some reason CMake itself wants to link it in generating an intermediate executable in `cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" ..`. 3) I'm using `3.19.0-rc1`. 4) I'll update my question.

Comment: I'm honestly stumped, I've never had to deal with such an old toolchain before. Try asking the cmake discourse instead. There are cmake developers there who might better be able to answer your question: https://discourse.cmake.org/